# SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized when excute comand with ID from gridview

Tags: asp.net

Please advice me to correct my code, i want to retrieve data to a textbox from grid-view, passing "ID" as parameter on link clicked event in grid view ,but it does not work as expected,
My ASPX code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvcat" CssClass="table table-bordered font-13" Width="500px" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' OnClick="lnkView_Click">View</asp:LinkButton>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

And behide code:

```
 protected void lnkView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblCategory WHERE ID = @ID , con"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dtcategory = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dtcategory);
                con.Close();
                hfID.Value = ID.ToString();
                txtName.Text = dtcategory.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
                txtDescription.Text = dtcategory.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting values in `dtcategory  ??`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void lnkView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
   {
       int ID = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblCategory WHERE ID = @ID",con))
       {
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",ID); // this line was mising in your code
           using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
           {
               DataTable dtcategory = new DataTable();
               sda.Fill(dtcategory);
               con.Close();
               hfID.Value = ID.ToString();
               txtName.Text = dtcategory.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
               txtDescription.Text = dtcategory.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
           }

       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to correct as you guide and i got a new error message when i click on linkview,

```
{"Must declare the scalar variable \"@ID\"."}
```

although a already define @ID in my code,